# Make fixed footer that sits below scrollable body divs

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am trying to build a layout with a fixed header and footer bar, with two scrollable divs inside of them.

Here is a link to what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/Lv72mtk5/2/

And here is my CSS:

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
    height:100vh;
}


.leftside, .rightside {
    height:50vh;
    width:100%;

}

@media screen and (min-width:796px) {

    .leftside, .rightside {
    height:100vh;
    position: fixed;
    margin-bottom:400px;
    
}
}

.leftside {
    background:red;
}

.rightside {
    background:blue;
}

#topbar {
    width:100%;
    background: orange;
    z-index:100;
    display:inline-block;
}

#bottombar {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    background: orange;
    z-index:100;
    bottom: 0;
    margin:0;
     display: inline-block;

}

#add {
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    font-size:8vh;
    color:black;
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    line-height:1.25;
}

#search {
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    font-size:8vh;
    color:black;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
    line-height:1.25;
}

#menu {
    font-size:8vh;
    position: fixed;
    color:black;
    margin:0;
    right:0;
    line-height:1.25;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

My issue is that the footer bar is cutting off the bottom of the "content" within the scrollable divs, which is especially an issue in the mobile version.

How do I fix this so that the two scrollable divs fit within the header and footer without overlap?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Please put your code in your question, not in links.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to calculate the height (header/footer) and set a margin-top to this value on the main (content) element. In my example below (this is done with jQuery. It calculates the height from 'Header' and sets this value to margin top on the main content div. You can also calculate the height from the footer and set a margin-bottom value to the main content

```js
var headerOffset = function() {
  var headerHeight = $('header').height();
  $('.content').css('margin-top', headerHeight);
}

var footerOffset = function() {
  var footerHeight = $('.footer').height();
  $('.content').css('margin-bottom', footerHeight);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    headerOffset();
    footerOffset();
});
```

```css
header {
  background-color: gray;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  border-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  padding: 4rem 0;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum ana</h1>
</header>
<body>
  <main class="content">
    Main content
  </main>
  <div class="footer">
    This is my footer
  </div>
</body>
```

If you have any questions feel free to ask!

Comment: thanks so much! this worked for the header, but I can't seem to make it work for the footer. 

is this code correct?

  var footerOffset = function() {
  var footerHeight = $('footer').height();
  $('.content').css('margin-bottom', footerHeight);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    footerOffset();
});

Comment: Updated my code snippet, that should work. If you have any trouble, please let me know!